# Button inside the GridSplitter not working WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I put the button inside the gridsplitter. my intention is to make clickable gridsplitter as well as slideable. my problem is after putting button inside the grid splitter, totally cannot drag by mouse. how can i configure the grid splitter to clickable and slideable.

```
<GridSplitter BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"  >
                <GridSplitter.Template>                        
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">                            
                        <Grid>
                            <Button Name="btnSplit" Content="⁞"  >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SplitterClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btnSplit}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </GridSplitter.Template>
            </GridSplitter>
```

Best Rgds
df

Comment: Why would you have a click event on a splitter?  You need to click to slide.

Comment: when i click the button, the slider will go to sudden position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to subscribe `MouseDoubleClick` event on `GridSplitter`:

```
<GridSplitter BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"  >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SplitterClickCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</GridSplitter>
```

If `MouseDoubleClick` event is not suitable for you, you can try to subscribe to `MouseDown` or `MouseLeftButtonDown.`